# How to configure Category product listings in Mobile?

Tags: css, product-list, magento2.2.6, category-products, mobile

We knew the steps to configure the product listings in Magento 2 on Desktop view and done successfully as per our need. Now, we wanted to show *2 products per row in portrait mode* and *3 products per row in landscape mode* on Mobiles.

We have configured to show 5 products per row in desktop view on Category pages. Because of this, we are getting an empty space in mobile.

Have read the posts regarding the product listings but none of the solutions are working for us.

We have also tried in adjusting the width of product listing grid but that too is not working.

[image]

Could anyone please guide me with this?

Comment: override using css